# Проверка внутри Expression на null

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, я хочу принимать на вход `Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expr`, где будет указано поле с которым нужно что-то сделать.

Все бы хорошо, но если я получаю свойство, которое находится во внутреннем объекте и оно равно null, то я вылетаю.

Например, `x=>x.Prop1.Prop2.Prop3`

На вопросики в выражении, компилятор ругается...:

> An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Я как-нибудь могу, получив данный Expression динамически его модифицировать?

Comment: x=>x?.Prop1?.Prop2?.Prop3

Comment: An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Comment: a try catch разве не ловит?

Comment: отловите и отправьте null в этом случае

Comment: А как дальше это выражение используется? Разбирается своим провайдером? Спускается в один из стандартных? В какой именно?

Comment: _Я как-нибудь могу, получив данный Expression динамически его модифицировать?_ - да, его можно модифицировать

Comment: Если коротко, то проблема не в Expression, а в провайдере, который его выполняет ака "я получаю свойство, которое находится во внутреннем объекте и оно равно null, то я вылетаю". EF на таком не вылетает, например. Обработка null и вообще обработка выражения в целом - полностью на совести провайдера. Если вылетает - допишите провайдер так, чтобы не вылетал.

Comment: @PashaPash тянет на ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash провайдер это просто тот кто разбирает выражение или есть какие то интерфейсы для этого?

Comment: @iluxa1810 провайдер - это тот, кто реально выполняет IQueryable, IQueryable.Provider. Он внутри обычно или вызывает IQueryable.Expression.Compile (если это LINQ to Objects), или пробегает визитором по IQueryable.Expression и превращает АСТ C# в АСТ SQL (например), и выполняет уже SQL (EF).

Answer (score 1):

За проверку на null и вообще за придание смысла вызову свойства в коде отвечает провайдер. Если ваш окончательный провайдер - это обычный LINQ to Objects, т.е. если вы просто компилируете это выражение в `Func<SomeB, int?>` - напишите просто `Func<SomeB, int?>`, выражения вам не нужны.

LINQ to Objects все равно, отдаете вы ему Expression, или делегат - он все равно Expression в этот делегат скомпилирует, отдать сразу делегат проще и дешевле.

Если у вас нужны именно Expression, т.е. предполагается некая динамическая работа с этим деревом выражений до того, как оно будет скомпилировано LINQ to Objects, то добавьте больше динамики в эту работу, дополнительным визитором. Допишите проверки на null на лету. Примерно вот так:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class SomeA
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class SomeB
    {
        public SomeA SomeA { get; set; }
    }

    class NullPropagationVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        [return: NotNullIfNotNull("node")]
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return base.Visit(node);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                return WrapInConditional(node);
            }
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }

        private Expression WrapInConditional(MemberExpression node)
        {
            var targetType = node.Type;
            bool addConvert = false;

            if (targetType.IsValueType)
            {
                targetType = typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(targetType);
                addConvert = true;
            }

            var nullCheck = Expression.Equal(node.Expression, Expression.Constant(null));
            var isNull = Expression.Constant(null, targetType);
            var visitedNode = base.VisitMember(node);
            Expression isNotNull = addConvert ? Expression.Convert(visitedNode, targetType) : visitedNode;

            return Expression.Condition(nullCheck, isNull, isNotNull);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
        {
            if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            {
                return Visit(node.Operand);
            }
            return base.VisitUnary(node);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression<Func<SomeB, int?>> ex = someb => someb.SomeA.MyProperty;

            var result = ((Expression<Func<SomeB, int?>>)new NullPropagationVisitor().Visit(ex)).Compile();

            Console.WriteLine(result(new SomeB { }) == null); // True, null
            Console.WriteLine(result(new SomeB { SomeA = new SomeA { MyProperty = 42 } })); // 42
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то не работает, если добавить еще уровней...=( someb.SomeA.SomeB.MyProperty

Comment: Хотя... если такую цепочку сделать вверх на основе вашего ответа, то все работает https://prnt.sc/vwix9i

Comment: @iluxa1810 можно вместо этого вызов base.VisitMember добавит, тогда внутренние замены тоже отработают

Comment: Поправишь ответ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 подправил, но сильно не проверял :)

Answer (score 0):

Может такой вариант

```
(x=>{ try { return x.Prop1.Prop2.Prop3 } catch { return null;}})
```

элегантнее возможно это

```
(myLambda)


myLambda = () => ....
```

Comment: Сработает, но должно быть более элегантное решение.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну не знаю. Элегантнее это обернуть саму лямбду в какую нибудь переменную/ф-ю.

Comment: Исключения - это медленно.